# Can we get a single SAS token for all the files in container?

Tags: typescript, azure, authentication, azure-blob-storage

I have typescipt application which upload the files to Azure blob storage.
I need to open a new windows and show the list of blobs in that container.
the container is a private one.
To View\upload a specific file in the container we need a SAS token of each file.
But its not possible to include SAS token for each file in the code.
Can we get a Common SAS token to view/Download all the files in that particular container folder.

Comment: Have you tried to create a sas token at the container level?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this by having all the files in the same private container and you need to create the SAS token on the blob container at the container level.